# Nagios/Centreon Error : Return code 127 is out of bounds : Plugin may be missing

Tags: python, linux, debian, monitoring, nagios

As part of an IT project, I worked with Nagios.
In order to get the value of a temperature sensor, I create a python plugin that will read the value in a database, and print in on screen.

The problem is that when I want to monitor the service based on this plugin, it is displayed as **CRITICAL** in the Centreon web interface with error "`(Return code 127 is out of bounds) plugin may be missing`".

Here is a summary of my installations :

- Nagios + NDOutils (+Centreon Web Interface) Install on Debian 7.5 :
  http://fr.scribd.com/doc/239973292/1-Installation-Manuelle-de-Nagios-Centreon-Debian#scribd
- I create a python plugin "`cigne_plugin.py`" that will read the value in a database, and print in on screen.
- Added file "`cigne_python.py`" in `/usr/local/nagios/libexec`
- In file `/usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg`, `$USER1$` macro is define on `/usr/local/nagios/libexec`
- In `/usr/local/nagios/etc/checkcommands.cfg`, I added these lines :

  ```
  define command{
      command_name        arduino_temp_sensor
      command_line        $USER1$/cigne_plugin.py
  }
  ```
- In `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg`, I added these line:

  ```
  define command{
      command_name        arduino_temp_sensor
      command_line        $USER1$/cigne_plugin.py
  }
  ```
- In `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg` :

  ```
  define service{
      use             local-service
      host_name           localhost
      service_description     Arduino Temp
      check_command               arduino_temp_sensor
      notification_enabled        0
  }
  ```
- Add command "`arduino_temp_sensor`" in the Centreon Web Interface (Configuration -> Commands)
- Add service "Arduino Temp" in Centreon Web Interface (Configuration -> Services)
- Check the files rights
- Check that the script can be execute
- Check the files owners
- Check users and groups
- In `/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg`, my service is create for "localhost"

I tried with a plugin version commenting all the code, and that only returns a "`sys.exit(2)`", problem is not from the code.

Comment: What are the permissions of /usr/local/nagios/libexec/cigne_plugin.py.  Can you run an ls -l on it and post the results?  Does your script call some other process?  How are you accessing the database?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios 157 Aug  6 11:58 cigne_plugin.py`

The script only do a `sys.exit(0)` for the moment.

Comment: And with only the sys.exit(0) it still gives Return code 127?  Can you try adding a shebang as the first line of the cigne_plugin.py script like this:  #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: Yes, it still gives Return code 127. I already added a shebang, the same you said : `#!/usr/bin/python`, I also tried with `#!/usr/bin/env python`, give me the same result.

Comment: I'm going to add some more troubleshooting as an Answer just because I need more space.  This isn't a final answer for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try building test_wrapper.sh shell script to see if there are some more general issues or if it's just isolated to python.

```
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# pwd
/usr/local/nagios/libexec
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# cat <<EOF >> test_wrapper.sh
> #!/bin/sh
> echo "OK"
> exit 0
> EOF
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# cat test_wrapper.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "OK"
exit 0
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# ls -al test_wrapper.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 joe joe 27 Aug  6 15:48 test_wrapper.sh
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# chmod a+x test_wrapper.sh
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# ls -al test_wrapper.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 joe joe 27 Aug  6 15:48 test_wrapper.sh
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# ./test_wrapper.sh
OK
```

**"OK"** shows that the output is fine.

```
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# echo $?
0
```

**Return Code** of **0** shows that the return code is fine.

Now let's build a bare-bones test_wrapper.py to eliminate any issues with the contents of the python code.

```
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# cat <<EOF >> test_wrapper.py
> import sys
>
> def main():
>         print "OK"
>         sys.exit(0)
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>         main()
> EOF
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# cat test_wrapper.py
import sys

def main():
        print "OK"
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# ls -al test_wrapper.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 joe joe 124 Aug  6 15:58 test_wrapper.py
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# chmod a+x test_wrapper.py
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# ls -al test_wrapper.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 joe joe 124 Aug  6 15:58 test_wrapper.py
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# python test_wrapper.py
OK
```

**"OK"** shows that the output is fine.

```
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# echo $?
0
```

**Return Code** of **0** shows that the return code is fine.

Finally let's add in command and service definitions so we can test it through the Nagios web interface.

Modify `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg`

**NOTE:**  Let's only modify the one `commands.cfg` file so that we don't have duplicate command definitions to confuse Nagios.  We'll ignore `checkcommands.cfg` for now.

Add:

```
define command {
        command_name                    sh_test_wrapper
        command_line                    $USER1$/test_wrapper.sh
        register                        1
}
define command {
        command_name                    python_test_wrapper
        command_line                    /usr/bin/python $USER1$/test_wrapper.py
        register                        1
}
```

Modify `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg`

Add:

```
define service{
    use             local-service
    host_name           localhost
    service_description     sh test wrapper
    check_command               sh_test_wrapper
    notification_enabled        0
    register                        1
}
define service{
    use             local-service
    host_name           localhost
    service_description     python test wrapper
    check_command               python_test_wrapper
    notification_enabled        0
    register                        1
}
```

Let's verify the configuration files

```
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

And restart Nagios.

```
[joe@joeyoung.io libexec]# service nagios restart
```

Let's see if these very basic checks work and see if we can't narrow down the problem more.

Comment: Okay, i'm gonne try that. In any case, thanks a lot for your help and answers

Comment: These checks doesn't appear in both Centreon and Nagios interface. I did exactly the same things you did.

Comment: Odd. Where there any errors reported in the verification step when you executed nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg?  Can you try adding "register                        1" to your service definitions then restart the nagios service?  I'll update the text of the Answer.

Comment: No error when executing `nagios -v /usr/local/etc/nagios.cfg`.
Already add `register 1`.

But, with any users, when I do `/usr/local/nagios/cigne_plugin.py`, I get :

`bash: ./cigne_plugin.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Ok it looks like /usr/bin/python doesn't exist on your system.  Change the first line of the python script to #!/usr/bin/env python  and that should take care of the "bad interpreter" issue.

Comment: Also, is it possible for you to paste the contents of your original python script that called to the database that was erroring with Return Code 127?  It's possible that your original script was fine except for the handling of the return code.  127 bitshifted eight bits to the right = 0, which is the OK return code for Nagios.  It could be as simple as fixing the return code / exit status code handling if that's really the issue.

Comment: When I put `#!/usr/bin/env python`, I get  :         
`defab@nagios:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ ./cigne_plugin.py`      
`: No such file or directory  
`

Comment: can you execute "which python" and post the results?

Comment: `defab@nagios:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ which python

/usr/bin/python
`

Comment: Ok, don't know why the shebang's not working. You can remove it and add "/usr/bin/python" in front of the "$USER1$/test_wrapper.py" part of the python_test_wrapper command definition in commands.cfg.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: I forgot to add service and command in the Web interface.. test_wrapper_py is now working in Centreon, but doesn't appear in Nagios

Comment: Ok, I just modified my command definition (adding `/usr/bin/python` before $USER1$ macro) in the commands.cfg file, check the nagios.cfg, restart nagios service, and it's working now, in both Nagios & Centreon ! Thank you very very very very much for your help !